# One specific domain returns a 403 Forbidden error

Tags: apache-httpd, domain

I'm rolling out a new Drupal 9 site to a RHEL server. I have three possible domains/subdomains for accessing the site: portal.yln.info, [www.yln.info](http://www.yln.info), and yln.info. Those three work on our current Drupal 7 site on that server. When I switch to the new conf file, portal.yln.info and [www.yln.info](http://www.yln.info) load the site just fine, but yln.info throws a 403 (and you would know that that yln.info is the URL I ultimately want them at). And if I turn off the SSL redirect and call yln.info with http instead of https, it works. The SSL cert is a wildcard for *.yln.info (and again, yln.info is working fine on the old Drupal site on the same server). I am at a complete loss. I don't know if it's an Apache issue or a Drupal issue. (I've posted on the Drupal site as well because this site is supposed to go live today and I'm scrambling.) There are no errors in the Apache log.

Here's my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ylnsys@yln.info

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info
        Redirect "/" "https://yln.info/"
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yln/web
        ServerName portal.yln.info
        ServerAlias www.yln.info
        ServerAlias yln.info
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/yln.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/yln>
                Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                RewriteEngine On
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: I am looking at /var/log/httpd/error_log. There are other entries in there (we have several sites on this server) but none relate to my request. I'm also looking at the Drupal log messages but there isn't anything there because Apache is cutting me off.

So while the new site is sitting on the production server (but not actually in production), I'm accessing it via new.yln.info. I have an entry in my Windows hosts file for that mapping. When I do the switch, I rename the conf files pointing to the old site and the new.yln.info site. Then I set up the new conf file for the new portal.yln.info/www.yln.info/yln.info site.

**Update 2**: Drupal does have a .htaccess file which could theoretically cause problems. I can't say that I understand everything it's doing. Here it is:

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|
\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config)$|^#.*#
$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Add correct encoding for SVGZ.
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

# Most of the following PHP settings cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and
# Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::bootEnvironment() for settings that can be
# changed at runtime.

# PHP 7, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
</IfModule>

# PHP 8, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Set a fallback resource if mod_rewrite is not enabled. This allows Drupal to
# work without clean URLs. This requires Apache version >= 2.2.16. If Drupal is
# not accessed by the top level URL (i.e.: http://example.com/drupal/ instead of
# http://example.com/), the path to index.php will need to be adjusted.
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  FallbackResource /index.php
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install\.php) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(rebuild\.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core
  RewriteRule ^ %1/core/%2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  # Rewrite install.php during installation to see if mod_rewrite is working
  RewriteRule ^core/install\.php core/install.php?rewrite=ok [QSA,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # For security reasons, deny access to other PHP files on public sites.
  # Note: The following URI conditions are not anchored at the start (^),
  # because Drupal may be located in a subdirectory. To further improve
  # security, you can replace '!/' with '!^/'.
  # Allow access to PHP files in /core (like authorize.php or install.php):
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/[^/]*\.php$
  # Allow access to test-specific PHP files:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/system/tests/https?\.php
  # Allow access to Statistics module's custom front controller.
  # Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
  # custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics\.php$
  # Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
  # Specifically, disallow autoload.php from being served directly.
  RewriteRule "^(.+/.*|autoload)\.php($|/)" - [F]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent double compression.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1,E=no-brotli:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Various header fixes.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  # Disable Proxy header, since it's an attack vector.
  RequestHeader unset Proxy
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details.  If the logs don't show a 403 error, the odds are good you're looking in the wrong log file.  Do the logs show **any** activity?  They should at least show requests coming from your client IP.  If not, then you're looking at the wrong logs.  How are you directing your browser requests to the new/test site while the old/production site is still running?

Comment: `grep` your logs for 403. Don't re-use log filenames. My preference is for every `xxxLog` directive to use a unique name, so I can tell which VHost is logging what.  One pair (`error` and `access`) is at the topmost level, in `httpd.conf`; another error/access pair for each VHost, as well as for each SSL Vhost. Make your `new.conf` logfile names **different** from your production logfiles.  Keeping things as separated as possible will hopefuly reduce the confusion.  Ideally, spin up the new site on a separate server or separate VM so your testing and production sites don't interact.

Comment: @JimL. I created new error and access logs but Apache isn't writing to them. Nevertheless, I discovered that it's logging in ssl_error_log. It says `Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`. Why is it looking in `/var/www/html` when I've told it to look in `/var/www/html/yln/web`?

Comment: How can I do a temporary redirect from https://yln.info to https://www.yln.info (for those that have yln.info bookmarked)? I tried several ways but they all throw errors.

Comment: StackExchange hijacked my strings. The above comment is supposed to say `yln.info` to `www.yln.info`.